# Async scope in Mule doesn't have copy of MuleMessage?

Tags: asynchronous, mule

I have following flow in my Mule app:

```
<flow name="UpdateStatusFlow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="UpdateStatusFlow" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>    
        <async processingStrategy="asynchronous">
            <request-reply>
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="request"/>
                <vm:inbound-endpoint path="reply"/>
            </request-reply>
        </async>
        <custom-transformer class="com.example.EanTransformer"/>   
</flow>
```

In async scope I depend on what has come to vm:inbound-endpoint and I assumed it is copy of that payload, so another copy is sent to EanTransformer which also modify payload. But it seems that no copy is made because in async flow I get already modified by EanTransformer ean code, which is not what I expected. If I add some delay in EanTransformer everything is fine, which means for me that this transformer haven't modify the message yet.

So the question is: if async scope really gets copy of the message (as it is written here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference) or work on the same message as next components? Or am I doing something wrong?

I am using Mule 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the referenced page further, it states that:

> Even though the Async scope receives a copy of the Mule message, the payload is not copied. The same payload object(s) will be referenced by both Mule messages: the one that continues down the original flow and the one processed by the Async scope.
>
> In other words, if the payload of your message is a mutable object
>   (for example a bean with different fields in it) and a message
>   processor in your async scope changes the value of one of the fields,
>   the message processors outside of the Async scope will see the changed
>   values.

Answer (score 0):

The Async flow does not receive a Copy of the message - rather it receives the original payload. So any changes to the payload should be done before the Async flow. Here it is clearly written:

> Even though the Async scope receives a copy of the Mule message, the payload is not copied. The same payload object(s) will be referenced by both Mule messages: the one that continues down the original flow and the one processed by the Async scope.
>
> In other words, if the payload of your message is a mutable object (for example a bean with different fields in it) and a message processor in your async scope changes the value of one of the fields, the message processors outside of the Async scope will see the changed values.